# How to get data from Power BI to BigQuery?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, powerbi

I need to transfer my data from a Power BI dashboard to BigQuery.

The goal is to do it in a way that it can be integrated into the pipeline to automate the process (the dashboard is updated with new data, that data is extracted and loaded into BigQuery).

*I know it may sound strange and that it's the opposite of the usual process but that's the problem I'm having.*

*I'm only provided with a dashboard (I don't know the original source and I don't have access to it) from which I need to extract the data and load it into BigQuery to work with it, but I can't find the way to do that.*

Thanks :)

Comment: If you do not have enough access to find out what the data source is, then better point your efforts to solve this problem, instead of trying to find an obviously wrong way to workaround it. To read the data, you can connect to the [XMLA endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-premium-connect-tools), but without any support from the report owners, I don't think you can do that either.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice!
I agree with you, but that's the scenario I'm facing.

I will continue to investigate how to work with XMLA to see if it is possible to extract the data in this way.

Greetings and thanks again!